# Sync TFS 2015 GIT to VSTS GIt

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

We have TFS 2015 Git, and looking for options to sync all the changes in onprem TFS GIT to VSTS Git . Could you please throw some thoughts on how to achieve it ?

Options that I have in my thoughts : -

1)Write a server side plugin to git push to VSTS on everytime checkin happens 
2)On post TFS build step, git push to VSTS

(Every time I check in , idea is to sync the changes to VSTS GIT)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sync TFS 2015 git repo to VSTS git repo automatically, you just need **a CI build in TFS2015 or VSTS** to achieve it.

Such as use the CI build in TFS 2015 to sync the VSTS repo automatically, you can follow below steps:

### 1.    Create a CI build in TFS 2015

In your TFS 2015 project where the git repo hosted -> create a build definition with the TFS 2015 git repo as repository -> enable CI with all branches included.

[image]

### 2.    Add a PowerShell task to sync TFS2015 git repo to VSTS

Add a PowerShell task in the build definition with below script:

```
if ( $(git remote) -contains 'vsts' )
{
    git remote rm vsts 2>&1|Write-Host
    echo 'VSTS Account removed'
}


git remote add vsts https://Personal%20Access%20Token:{PAT}@{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_git/{repo}

git checkout ${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME} 2>&1|Write-Host
git reset --hard origin/master 2>&1|Write-Host
echo 'update local branch with remote successfully'
git push  vsts ${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME} -f 2>&1|Write-Host
```

**Note:** the vsts remote should be added with credential. And it uses PAT for authentication in the VSTS git repo URL. And you just need to replace the real PAT, accountname, projectname and reponame in the URL `https://Personal%20Access%20Token:{PAT}@marinaliu.visualstudio.com/{project}/_git/{repo}`.

Save the build definition, and now when any branches are updated in TFS 2015 git repo, VSTS git repo will be synced automatically for the corresponding branches.

Comment: Thanks @Marina Liu.!!